# Error with asreml.d package in R-2.14.0

Tags: r

I installed `asreml.d` on `R 2.14.0` using *Install packages from local zip files*  from the *Packages* menu. When I try to load the package with `library(asreml.d)`, I get the following error

```
Error in library(asreml.d) : 
  package ‘asreml.d’ does not have a NAMESPACE and should be re-installed
```

Error occur even after re-installation. Any comment, idea and solution to fix this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Contact the package maintainers???

Comment: I guess this is due to  [new feature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7998438/707145)  of `R 2.14.0`

Comment: Run it under 2.13.x or get a version of the package specifically built for 2.14.x .

Comment: Do you have a link to the source code?

Comment: I use `lme4` frequently and need to use `ASREML` for some specific functionalities  yet not available in `lme4`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maintainers of the package need to update the package to include a `NAMESPACE` file.

That said, you  might have luck inserting the `NAMESPACE` file yourself as a hack.  It looks like ASReml is closed source, but you have the .zip file.  Try unzipping it.  Then, create a simple text file containing:

```
exportPattern("^[^\\.]")
```

Save it as `NAMESPACE` (be careful that there is no extension like .txt, Windows sometimes sneaks these in). Place `NAMESPACE` in the top folder of the unzipped package (should be something like `asreml.d/`; there will also be a `DESCRIPTION` file there). If there is an `MD5` file, you should probably delete it. Now, re-zip the `asreml.d/` directory. See if the new zip file works.

For more on `NAMESPACE`, see http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces .

NB This might be bad advice.  But it seems like it would work. It won't hurt anything.

Comment: R 2.14.x will add a NAMESPACE file automatically if its not already in the package so the maintainers just need to rebuild it for R 2.14.x .  For example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998438/r-2-14-detect-packages-without-namespace

Comment: @G. Grothendieck  True, but would this work in the meantime, while MYaseen208 is waiting for maintainers to build with R 2.14.x?

Comment: Surely it would be easier to make no changes at all and just rebuild it under 2.14.x than to add a NAMESPACE and then rebuild it with 2.13.x.

Comment: @jthetzel: Thanks for your reply. I did not get any error after followed your guidelines except this warning `Warning message:
In readLines(file) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/Users/R/win-library/2.14/asreml.d/NAMESPACE'`. Any suggestion.

Comment: @MYaseen208  I think that warning is safe.  Does the package load fine now?  To prevent it in the future, perhaps make sure there are no blank lines at the end of the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck  I agree with you that the maintainers should just build it with 2.14.x.  However, what I glean from OP is that only the Windows binary is available to OP (and not the source, as it is closed for this package), and that the maintainers cannot be relied upon to rebuild in a timely fashion.  So, this answer is just a sub-optimal way to get buy for the moment.

Comment: @jhetzel, He hadn't mentioned that he did not have access to the source but if that is the case then I agree.