# Loading QRMlib in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to install QRMlib which is a package which has been taken off CRAN to be updated. I have installed all the dependents, including those that have also been removed to be updated. I have downloaded an archived version but when I try to load it using
library(QRMlib)

I get the following error:
"package ‘QRMlib’ does not have a NAMESPACE and should be re-installed"

What do I do?
I have reinstalled and retried over and over but get the same problem. I am on a Mac if that makes any difference.
I know an update of the lib is on its way but its urgent.

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012596/error-with-asreml-d-package-in-r-2-14-0

Comment: I would try downloading this: http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/src/contrib/Archive/QRMlib/QRMlib_1.4.5.1.tar.gz and installing from source: `install.packages(file.choose(),repos=NULL,type="source")`. You might *also* need to follow the advice in the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to revert back to R 2.13 (and build the package from source), since that version did not require that packages have namespaces. There is still a binary version of 2.13.2  at http://r.research.att.com/  Or I suppose you could rebuild the package with a namespace, but this is probably a case of "if you have to ask, you probably can't do it."  (I know I can't.) There are instructions about running different versions of R in the Mac-R-FAQ.

If the package has C or Fortran code you will also need the XCode development tools and all of the necessary information is at the AT&T website that Simon Urbanek runs. I'm thinking that's probably the case, since one of the files describing the QRMlib package says it used the mingw C compiler for installation on Windows. You should say where you got this package and offer its full file name, since that will help determine what steps are necessary.